# How to disable the future dates in ajax calender extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code i am using in my aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ReqFromTxtBox" runat="server" class="textBox" Width="155px" onKeyPress="javascript: return false;" onPaste="javascript: return false;">
</asp:TextBox> 
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="ReqFromTxtBox_CalendarExtender" runat="server" PopupButtonID="ReqFromCalendarBtn" TargetControlID="ReqFromTxtBox">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

For **diabling Future Dates** on  **pageload** event set `EndDate` to Today Date using `DateTime.Now`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ReqFromTxtBox_CalendarExtender.EndDate = DateTime.Now;   //to disable future  Dates
}
```

and for **Disabling past dates** you have to set `StartDate` to Today :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReqFromTxtBox_CalendarExtender.StartDate= DateTime.Now;   //to disable past Dates
}
```

[Reference Link How To Disable Past of Future Date of Calendar Extender](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/disable-future-and-past-date-of-ajax-calendar-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Comment: i tiied but i am getting error Error 1 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not contain a definition for 'EndDate' and no extension method 'EndDate' accepting a first argument of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you setting it in same page or usercontrol codebehind where ou have used calendar?

Comment: I am setting it in the .cs file for the same aspx page

Comment: try removing the control and add it again on page from tool box